# Should I use public setter to set private attribute value inside class?

Tags: php, oop, class, coding-style, refactoring

Lets assume I have a class Test, which has got a private attribute called `$_list`, and a public setter.
Public setter is used to set the attribute value from the outside.

```
class Test {
    private $_list;

    public function getList() {
        return $this->_list;
    }

    public function setList($list) {
        $this->_list = $list;
    }

    public function initialize() {
        $list = array();

        /* ... Some code that fills the $list with values etc. ... */

        // 1) Set value directly
        $this->_list = $list;

        // 2) Use public setter
        $this->setList($list);
    }
}
```

The question is - do I need to use public setter to set private attribute value inside class?
Which way is are better - #1 or #2? And why?
Which way do you prefer?
I would like to see a complete answer with the explaination of advantages and disadvantages of each way.

Thanks.

Comment: Either is fine. The function call has a /very/ slight overhead, but not enough to make a difference. Other than that, they're basically the same in this case. One benefit of using the function is if there is additional logic used when setting the variable, in which case it'll keep things consistent without the need for copying the code.

Comment: What's the point of giving public access to a private variable? O_O

Comment: @AlexLunix There can be various reasons, not for the example given, but if (as per my comment) there were further logic such as validation of the value, then you don't want people just setting whatever value they like direct to the object property, you want them going through the validation.

Comment: @AlexLunix ideally more is done to validate the input, or the interal structure of the object is more complex than a simple set of variables.

Comment: @ Alex Lunix Setter can once become something more than `$this->_list = $list`. Giving public access to private property through setter allows to handle some pre-processing functionality, indirect assignation, allowing to check value before assign it etc.

Comment: It's for this scenario that I'm disappointed that PHP implemented traits before property syntax (which still isn't on the 5.5 horizon from what I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was written above, both are acceptable, but the correct answer is: **Rather use the direct attribute access**, but sometimes you better use the setters.

Number 1, (property access) Pros:

- Easily readable and slighty faster
- Gives you the approach that this is an simple attribute of the object

Number 2, (setter) Pros:

- You can do custom action on setting the attribute (e.g. initialize other attributes, caches, or call a method on the parameter object)
- You treat the attribute as a sub-element of the class, which may have own logic implemented.

I think that proposing that there is no logic behind using a variable is more important. **If it is simple, make it look simple.** If it's not, you can still use setters.

You could also ask the same about getters versus property access, the above applies as well.

Comment: Thanks you for you answer, GaborSch. Let's wait for a little bit and see if there are some more guys who want to share there opinion. If there won't be other answers better than yours, I'll accept yours.

Comment: Thanks! Actually it is true for all object-oriented languages, not only for PHP.